# Input type checkbox values

Tags: html, checkbox, input

I am looking at [this w3schools checkbox demo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox)

I notice that input doesn't get checked value when checked. Is this valid html?

I tried using this with php forms and the value if "on" when checked.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: console.log(document.querySelectorAll(":checked")) shows the number of checked boxes. What is the issue? That you cannot see the checked property when inspecting the code?

Comment: To get the value of all checkboxes via PHP form, you should give them all either different `name`s or the same `name` that ends with `[]` (e.g. `name="checkboxes[]"`), so PHP would be able to make an array from their values.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a checkbox is whatever the `value` attribute says it is with (in the case of checkboxes) `on` as the default.

Its checked status (available via the `checked` property in JS) determines if it will be a successful control (i.e. appear in the submitted form data at all) or not.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `checked="checked"` so that that initial wont be checked

```css
/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
<label class="container">One
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Three
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Four
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer? If so, please add explanatory text (what did you change and why). Or if it was posted by mistake, then please delete it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).